# RandomAccessFile - System cannot find path specificied

Tags: java, io, randomaccessfile

Good day,
I've been working on a program for calculating and also saving trainings and calories used between them and I've hit rock bottom.

This is my RandomAccessFile:

```
RandomAccessFile dat = new RandomAccessFile("training\\"+lastTraining+".dat","rw");
```

It doesn't work. It returns me "The system cannot find path specified."
Now, I don't have folder neither file created, because I want program to create them. What am I doing wrong? I already tried all kind of slashes in path but nothing works.

Thanks!

Comment: You should first create the folder. `RandomAccessFile` only creates a file in an existing directory.

Comment: @DownbeatTax realized you may not have visibility on the comment I added to my deleted answer. `RandomAccessFile` constructor will fail with a non-existing file only if the read option is selected alone - it will actually create it if the write option is present. I suspect vanje's comment is a good way to start. Maybe also ensure you can actually create the file in that path through other means.

Comment: @vanje creating folder doesn't work. I tried several options, including going out of current folder(src) and then saving file there, without success.
I used this path: "..\\trainings\\"+lastTraining+".dat" 
I think I'm missing something to set it to relative directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried passing in the full path? 
E.g: instead of "training\file.dat" do

`(Windows) "C:/path/to/file/file.dat"
(Unix) "/path/to/file/file.dat"`

Edit: Note that the folder(s) you are trying to place the file in have to exist beforehand, as `RandomAccessFile` will not create them and throw the `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Yeah, this works. :D
But is there any way I could use relative paths?

Comment: You could try `String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");`

Comment: Try some debugging.... System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath()); This should tell you the path.

Comment: @TimCramer This works! It's a work-around but excellent work-around. Thanks!